# how to determine what page my script is run on

Tags: javascript, shopify

when my app is installed I create a script tag (through the shopify API). I am only interested in running this script on product view pages. what is a reliable way to check whether the script is run by a product view page? Should I ask the merchant to put something in to their liquid file manually?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work, in *your* JavaScript:

```
// If we are on a product page
if (window.location.pathname.indexOf('/products/') !== -1) {
 // What's the product handle?
 var productHandle = pathname.match(/\/products\/([a-z0-9\-]+)/)[1];
}
```

Comment: To this specific question: 
- Should I ask the merchant to put something in to their liquid file manually?
My answer:
- Please, I beg you: NO. As much as possible, don't add anything to the theme's files you won't able to remove later, and don't (even less) ask customers to edit their theme.

Answer (score 0):

The product page in Shopify always has a form on it that adds the product to the cart, so you can do something like this (assuming jQuery is available):

```
jQuery("form[action='/cart/add']").each(function() {
  console.log("I'm in ur product page");
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You can pass an extra function parameter specifying where the function was called from. I have used this kind of programming in a few projects with great success. For example:

```
function foo(data, moarData, caller) {
  if(caller != 'productPage') { return false; }
  ...
}
```

And you can specify the caller variable from the function call on the product view page:

```
var page = 'productPage';
foo('sharks', 'games', this.page);
```

Comment: thanks. I am not sure I understand. When I create a script tag, I give it a URL that will be called when the shop renders the pages. I have no control over what parameters the url will receive. could you clarify?

Comment: Ah, I see now what you mean. But yes, you do have some control over this. You can <script src="x.js" /> and then put a <script type="text/javascript"> foo('productPage'); </script> right afterwards. If you have control over WHERE the function is called FROM, then you definitely have control over sending extra values.

Comment: when I install a script tag, my URL is called from every page of the shop. the only parameter that they pass to the URL is the name of the shop. to make a call like you suggest I would need to ask the shop owner to enter this script in to the page. in other words, the owner would need to modify the shop's template file for the product view. I am trying to avoid this. I would like to be able to inspect DOM perhaps to determine which page I am on. if possible.

Answer (score -1):

Write some generic Javascript to query the current URL in the browser. You can easily tell if you're on a page, product or collection. Try a simple RegExp to do this. It would be pretty hard for a shop to mess up the URL structure since Shopify is hosted.

Comment: this is a good suggestion, thanks. Do you mean that the URL path stays the same even if the shop uses a custom domain? I also need to know the ID of the product shown on the current page. How would you fetch that?

Comment: Using the same technique, you can parse the handle of the product from the URL. Using that, your code can use the Ajax API to request the product and that would give you the ID. Again, totally possible with generic Javascript, but also clunky, since you really should not have to ask the server for the product as you already are handed it on a platter. Unfortunately, to get at the ID is not simple unless the script uses Liquid to extract the JSON of the product. Perhaps you can just do that in your injected script. 

    var product = {{product | json }};
    var id = product.id